# Microsoft PowerBI MySQL database connector not found issue

Tags: powerbi, mysql-connector, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to connect to my MySQL DB but facing:

> "MySQL database connector not found issue"

ande when I provide correct credential to connect. I get

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

as shown below. I know, there is some connector issue like version of connector or credential, but not able to find any way out.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved with following steps:

1. Uninstall earlier version of MySQL Connector and install newer: 6.6.5 from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=412152
2. Go to File => Options and settings => Data source settings. Then **Edit Permissions**, provide correct credentials.
3. Recheck.

Here are the complete steps given: [Connecting MySQL Database in Microsoft PowerBI](http://snippetnuggets.com/interviewQuestions/powerBI/basics/connecting-mysql-database-microsoft-powerbi.html)